# Setting start index to loop in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing a Web application using AngularJS. I am having a problem to use for loop in the html in AngularJS way. See my scenario below.

In AngularJS, we normally loop ng-repeat like this

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

But what I want to do is I want to set the start index for loop. In JavaScript, it is going to look like this.

```
for(var i=3;i<items.length;i++)
{
    //do something
}
```

As you can see, I set the start index(i) to 3. But how can I embed the code in html in AngularJS way? What I want is something like setting start index to ng-repeat. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use JavaScript's Array.slice function, you won't need to invoke Angular functions.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items.slice(3)">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank u. I used this one.

Answer (score 3):

```
ng-repeat="item in myItems" ng-if="$index>=3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: (startIndex - items.length)">
 </ul
```

This will work.